# How to convert date so it joins with date dimension table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a `ProdDate` column in `Product` table that is in the following format:

```
 1/2/2015 1:22:19 PM
```

I need to join this date column to retrieve more information from `DimDate` table. I am joining with a column name Date that has the following date format:

```
 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

What I have tried but still doesn't work:

```
 CONVERT(DATETIME, ProdDate, 101)
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, ProdDate, 101)
 CONVERT(DATETIME, ProdDate, 110)
 CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, ProdDate, 101) AS VARCHAR(10))
```

I have tried the above conversion on both `Date` and `ProdDate` column to join on but still can't get it to work. Anyone knows a work around?

Answer (score 1):

A Date dimension should not have a time component. Create separate date and time dimensions.

Either use an `int` 'coded' date key (e.g. 20150219) or Datatype `Date` for the Date Dimension key column.

In the latter case;  you would simply cast as Date:

```
cast(ProdDate as Date)
```

In the former

```
cast(CONVERT(char(8), ProdDate, 112) as int)
```

Re.: [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: There is actually a datecode column already exist that is in the format 20150219. Do you suggest I use that column to join? Will this be correct then:  
    ON CAST(ProdDate AS DATE) = DateCode

Comment: Yes.     use the key column

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. I'll try it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Both of your suggested ideas are not working. I receive the following error when I use the second code: **"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3/18/201' to data type int."** and for the first one, the error is: **"Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"**

Comment: post your table schema  and post your code. Modelling date dimensions this way works perfectly for me. BTW what sort of date is '3/18/201' ? Is your date column a varchar or a Date datatype?